# How to hide label in tableView with custom cells?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to be able to hide label(s) in a `tableView` if they are empty.
For example:
The `label` is populated with a variable `var name = String()` And if the `name`variable is empty, I want to hide the label. In a normal `ViewController`I would do:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        if name.isEmpty == true {
            nameLabel.isHidden = true
        }
```

How is this done in a `tableView`?

**EDIT***

I'm sorry for the unclear and badly formatted question. I´ll try again:

I have a `nameArray`, and a `numberArray`
The `nameArray` can contain blank("") spaces, and the `numberArray` can contain 0´s
When for example the `numberLabel`contains 0, I want it to be hidden. This can vary from row to row.

The nearest I have gotten is this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InfoCell") as! InfoCell


        cell.nameLabel.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.numberLabel.text = numberArray[indexPath.row]


        if numberArray.contains(0) {
            cell.numberLabel.isHidden = true
        }


    return cell

}
```

But this also hides all `labels with 0 in it.

How can I remove the`labels only containing one 0?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where is your label at in the tableView? Individual cells? P.S - the label would appear hidden if you don't have any text in it.

Comment: `if numberArray.contains(0) { ... }`, if you can describe what you'd like to expect from this line exactly, that would be helpful to find the actual solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your

```
if numberArray.contains(0) {
        cell.numberLabel.isHidden = true
    }
```

into:

```
if numberArray[indexPath.row] == 0  {
        cell.numberLabel.isHidden = true
    }
```

The same check can be done for nameArray as well.